# Stale connection in node.js + postgresql

Tags: node.js, postgresql

In my node app i am using express + postgresql. For postgresql i am using 'pg' module..

Consider my postgresql is restarted, then the pipe(connection) to the postgresql connection is broken and my application is not working. I have to restart my application to work normally.

How can i avoid the restart and make the pg module reconnect automatically. I think i am talking about `"Stale Connection"`. Please share your ideas.

My Connection String:

```
var conString = 'postgres://' + configPostgres.username + ':' + configPostgres.password + '@' + configPostgres.host + '/'+configPostgres.dbname;

var pgclient;
 pg.connect(conString, function(err, client, done) { 
    if(err){
        logger.info("In pgconnect");
        logger.error(err.stack);
        return;
    } else {
        pgclient = client;
    }
 });
```

Comment: You should create a connection pool: http://blog.argteam.com/coding/connection-pooling-with-node-postgres/

Answer (score 0):

Detect connectivity issues and release the application pool, by calling `pg.end()`

This will release all database connections and the connection pool at the same time, so next time you call `.connect` it will reinitialize the pool and try to create a physical connection again.